# Explain the output of this code about pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char *p = "Hello world";
    int *q;
    p++;

    q = (int*) p;
    q++;

    printf("\n %s\n%s", p, q);
}
```

The output of this program is this:

```
ello world
 world
```

Can anybody explain how this program works?

Comment: @Jonny Henly You realise that the ouput won't be on 2 lines, because no newline, and that the actual space before the second "world" is important?

Comment: @AntonH Didn't realize there was a space before `world`, my fault. But `"\n %s\n%s"` has 2 line breaks in it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly My mistake then. We were both right one one thing, you the newline, me the space :)

Comment: @AntonH No hard feelings : )

Comment: Well oops. I had warnings turned up to pedantic and treat-warnings-as-errors, so I get no output at all as this fails to compile (and rightly so).

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier. You could fix this by changing the `q` in the last line to `(char *)q`

Comment: On some systems, `q = (int *)p` may cause an alignment exception or other undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M Yeah, see 6.3.2.3. p7 It's straight undefined behavior, unless you got lucky and p happens to be aligned.

Comment: You want to read on *pointer arithmetic* (in C).

Answer (score 3):

In the `p++` line, you increment the address `p` by one, as that is the size of the `byte` type, so `p` ends up looking at the "e" in your string.

Then you assign the same address of `p` into `q`, so it also looks at "e". Then you increment `q`, but as it is a pointer to an integer (type `int`, which in your machine is 4 bytes long), it is incremented by four. So adding four to the "e" it was looking at before, it ends up looking at the space character.

Comment: I want to know whether we can saved ,set of letters in char type variable

Comment: No, you can only save one character in a variable of type  `char`. But in your example `p` is not of type `char`, it is of a type pointer to a certain address in memory where variables of type `char` are stored, so when printing it prints all the characters in that chunk of memory until a null character is found.

Comment: that means when I put a type of pointer it directs only to that that type values, such as it breaks the **Hello World ** to characters

Comment: Yes kind of, and if you put a pointer to type `int` looking to that same memory, it "breaks" it to integers. And as your integers are 4-bytes-wide, the `++` operator advances four bytes into the array.

Answer (score 0):

`char *p` initially points to first character of the string `Hello World`. The statement `p++` changes pointer `p` to point to second character of the  string. This explains you get `ello world` when you print the string using pointer `p` after incrementing it.

When you assign the pointer `p` to a pointer `q` which is a pointer to int. Incrementing the pointer `q` changes the pointer to point to `world`(it is pointing at the space character). It is due to fact that `int` is 4-bytes long in your machine and incrementing a pointer to int, increments the pointer content by 4 bytes. Therefore, when you print a string using pointer `q`, it prints `world`.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have incremented the pointer variable after storing the string (p++ and q++). where's in your printf statement you are printing the whole stirng % s not just a character thats why it is printing like that. I hope you got the answer!